# Parsing out paragraphs in one line of html using python

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

Given the flexibility of HTML codes, parsing out paragraphs as seen by a user through browser seems to be a quite non-trivial task.

For now, I have a not so robust solution:

```
tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(html, lxml.etree.HTMLParser()) if isinstance(html, basestring) else html 
for skiptag in ('//script', '//iframe', '//style', 
                '//link', '//meta', '//noscript', '//option'):    
    for node in tree.xpath(skiptag):
        node.getparent().remove(node)
paragraphs = lxml.etree.tostring(tree, encoding=unicode, method='text')
```

The problems I am facing are mainly about how to tackle abnormality (or say, free-styles).

One quite common case is that many paragraphs are written in one line (e.g. code below) in the HTML, and my code will parse them into one paragraph.

```
<p>bla, bla 1.</p><p><u><span class="colored"><strong>bla, bla 2.</strong></span></u></p><p>bla, bla. 3;</p><p>bla, bla. 3</p>
```

My questions are:

- is there any good ways in general to parse out paragraphs correctly?
- in this particular case, how should I optimize my code to correctly get paragraphs from one-line of HTML, given not only `<p>` can represent paragraph, but many other ways may be applied to the free-style?
- any general advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [html2text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text).

It may not do exactly what you want, but it's only a 500 line script, so it should be pretty easy to adapt it to your particular needs.

Answer (score 3):

Use the *xpath* method to loop over all paragraphs:

```
for para in tree.xpath("//p"):
    ...
```